# select algorithm to find element occurring more than n/2 in O(n)

Tags: java, algorithm, select, median

Without using Moore's algorithm or hash table, I need to find the element that occurs more than `n/2` times in an array.

I know I have to use the select algorithm using median of median. I am confused as to what select algorithm returns because if it returns the median how am I sure the element occurs more than `n/2` times in the array?

For example:

> a [] = {4, 1, 5, 7, 8}

5 is the median but it doesn't occur more than `n/2` times.

Now:

> a[] = {5, 5, 3, 4, 5, 5}

In this case the median is 5 and it occurs more than `n/2` times.

Comment: I don't get it. I thought if an element occurs more than n/2 times will be the median, isn't it?

Comment: Yes but the converse is not true, the median does not have to occur n/2 times

Comment: So just find the median and then check how often it occurs

Comment: Yes. I will have to find the median and just count its occurrences then.

Comment: Using a hash table will probably be faster than quickselect though

Comment: I have implemented it using my own version of hash table. I am finding alternate solutions. The hash table approach gives me O(n).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use select algorithm to find the the median element. Here if the element is more than n/2 times it is obvious that it is the median. Use Median of  median to get running time of O(n). The once you get the median element just count its occurrence in array which is again in linear time

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to suggest another method. This problem is called "finding the leader" (at least in Polish literature). Let's call an element occuring more than `n/2` times the leader of a sequence. The following observation is crucial - if there exists a leader in a sequence, after removing two *different* elements, the newly created sequence will have exactly the same leader as the original one. Why is that? If there is a leader, after removing two different elements, exactly one of them is the leader. The new sequence has `n - 2` elements and more than `(n / 2) - 1` occurences of the original leader, hence the original leader is the new leader. You repeat the deletion until all elements are equal. Then you can perform a linear check if the candidate is a leader.

Sample code (based on [this article](http://main.edu.pl/pl/user.phtml?op=lesson&n=36&page=algorytmika), unfortunately unavailable in English):

```
int leader = 0;
int number = 0; /* number of occurences of a leader candidate */
for (int k = 0; k < n; k++)
{
    if (number == 0)
    {
        //we set first element as a potential leader
        leader = a[k];
        number = 1;
    }
    else if (leader == a[k])
        //new leader occurence
        number++;
    else
        //delete two different elements
        number--;
}
//check if it really is the leader
number = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    if (a[i] == leader)
        number++;
if (number > n / 2)
    System.out.println(leader);
else
    System.out.println("There is no leader");
```

Comment: How do we find two different elements i  amortized O (1)? Two pointers?

Comment: By the way, it should be "at most one of them" I think

Comment: I don't think this works. Consider the sequence `[5,5,5,3,3,3,2,2,5,5]`. If I read the code correctly, it's going to report that there is no leader because at the end of the first pass, `leader == 2`.

Comment: @JimMischel It will report that there is no leader and that is true. In your example element `5` occurs `5` times and there are `10` elements in total, hence it isn't leader. There was a mistake in my answer, at least `n / 2` was supposed to be more than `n / 2`, I've corrected it. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: @NiklasB. it should be "exactly on of them". Assuming that the leader exists, it occurs more than `n / 2` times; from Dirichlet's pigeonhole principle if we take two different elements, exactly one of them is the leader.

Comment: That is Moore's algorithm, so it's not "another algorithm". See description in English here: http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~moore/best-ideas/mjrty/example.html

Comment: @Mateusz now that's just wrong. Take [1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3] clearly 3 is the leader and 1, 2 are two different elements none of which is the leader. You correctness proof still works, so no need to worry